# Idiomatic way to detect cause of SQLException before reporting to user

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, playframework

I am writing a database backed web server and I was wondering about the best practise/idiomatic way to implement the following:

So when a user creates account the server needs to insure that the username has not been already taken.  The username field in the database is defined as a unique key.  So rather than doing a two step process of checking the existence of the username and then adding it, I was hoping I could take advantage of the DBMS.  By this I mean, just add the record and trust that an SQLException will be thrown.

My issue is how to find the cause of the exception.  As in I certainly cannot return exception.getMessage() to the user but I need a way of identifying if it was due to a duplication in an unique key field that caused the error (and therefore let the user know) and not another type of issue that JDBC may throw (other issues should instead be logged).

I could try to parse e.getMessage() but I was hoping there would be a more full proof way to do this.

Comment: The common way is to do the two step process within a transaction. Your application logic should notify the user, not the SQL errors.

Comment: In general I find it a Bad Idea(TM) to use exceptions for non-exceptional flow control. I'd rather see feedback to the user that a username is not available *before* clicking the button, and resort to exception handling for the odd race condition.

Comment: Instead of parsing the error message, rather check for the SQL error number

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is capture the sqlexception, handle it (depends on your db provider exception codes) to transform into a new Exception like UserAlreadyExistException throwing it to the presentation layer. Finally in the presentation layer capture it and put an user-friendly message.